# Pulling information from two different tables and merging them in a news feed

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, feed

I have two different tables with different structures. When user does action A, a row gets inserted into table A in respect to the action, the same way for table B. When user does action B, a row gets inserted into table B.

Now I have a news feed that I want to show both these actions to other friends. How do I query both tables with different structure using MySQL, and then use PHP to construct update posts in a time sorted manner?

Just like in Facebook, A user update on his relationship status is different than a post he makes and attach a photo to it but they both appear in the same news feed although their structures and the type of data they carry is different. I appreciate if someone can shed some light on this and discuss a possible solution.

Comment: use inner join/left join on your both tables? `select a.*,b.* from table_a a inner join table_b b on b.user_id = a.user_id` ?

Comment: I don't want to join, but to merge them so I can sort them by time.

Comment: you can sort them from within your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach would be something like this:

```
SELECT
  'A' AS ActionType,
  ActionA_PK AS ActionPK,
  ActionA_Date AS ActionDate,
  <a description of action A> AS ActionDesc
FROM ActionA
UNION SELECT
  'B',
  ActionB_PK,
  ActionB_Date,
  <a description of action B>
FROM ActionB
ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
```

That folds the different actions together and orders them by date, with the most recent first. You can display them on the front end, and because you have their type (`A` or `B`) and their primary key you can identify them when posting back for processing when their link or button or whatever is clicked.

There's a [SQLFiddle example here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10316e/1).

The another [SQLFiddle example here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49e09b/1) which explains how the tables don't need to have the same structure to make this work.

Comment: Ed, Thanks for the solution, can you please explain how it works or give an example with data in it. I couldn't figure it our completely. I appreciate it :)

Comment: I actually figured out what you are trying to do. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah well - I was almost done with the example so I'll post [the link to the SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10316e/1) anyway :) If it doesn't help you it may help anyone who stumbles on this in the future. I'm glad my answer worked out for you - good luck!

Comment: Ed, The only problem with Union is that both tables should have the same number of columns, am I right ? How do you get around something like that if you have tables with different column sizes ? :(

Comment: In order to compensate for the column shortage, I added some padding columns as temp with 'empty' value to balance the lower number of columns in one table but I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: The *tables* don't have to have the same number of columns, the *results* do. The column types in the *results* have to be more or less the same - differing lengths won't be a problem. If the data types differ you can convert them. There's a [new SQL Fiddler here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49e09b/1) that shows this: the Photos table has more columns than the Relationships table, and three of the Photos columns (including the date the photo was taken) are worked into the description. The tables are different, but it still works because the *result* columns for each query match.

Comment: Good. It's a great one.